# Hive Regex_replace is giving Could not compile regexp pattern: error

Tags: regex, hive, hiveql, impala, regexp-replace

I am trying to replace "`[[`" and "`]]`" in my string and I am using two regex_replace functions to do that.

```
Select regexp_replace(regexp_replace("[[2020-03-23T10:33:03Z, 224554, training, 2019-05-06T15:53:23Z, Completed]]"
,"]]",""),"[[","")
```

It was working fine when I try to replace the first string which is "`]]`",but if I do the same for "`[[`" I am getting a compile error:

> Could not compile regexp pattern: [[ Error: missing ]: [[

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: can you use normal `replace`? reg replace may be considering [[ as part of its keyword.

Comment: replace is not working with hive version we have,translate is working same like replace.

Answer (score 1):

`[` and `]` characters have special meaning in regexp and should be escaped using double-backslash. Also you can combine both `[[` and `]]` in single regexp_replace using OR (`|`):

```
Select regexp_replace("[[2020-03-23T10:33:03Z, 224554, training, 2019-05-06T15:53:23Z, Completed]]"
,"\\]\\]|\\[\\[","")
```

Result:

```
2020-03-23T10:33:03Z, 224554, training, 2019-05-06T15:53:23Z, Completed
```

instead of two square brackets you can use single one with quantifier `\\]{2}` or `\\]+` for any number of brackets